# Evitar múltiples registros en MSQL y PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

tengo un problema con mi proyecto sobre un registro de horarios, el problema es que no se como evitar que alguien se registre el mismo día mas de dos veces. No puedo usar un `unique` en el campo de la fecha ya que eso evitaría que los otros usuarios se registren el mismo día y ese es precisamente el problema, el hecho de que usar el `unique` evita que los demás usuarios se registren de forma exitosa en la BDD. Aquí están los códigos:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro Entrada</title>
</head>
<body>
<img align=center src="../FondoIndex1.png" alt="Imagen de Background" />
<font face="arial" color="000001">
    <br><br>
    <h3>Por favor, ingrese sus datos.</h3>
    <form class="contacto_form" action="regHoraEntrada.php" method=post method=get name="contacto_form" id="contacto_form" style>
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>Registro de entrada</h1>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Usuario: </label>
            <input type=text size="50" name="usuario" id="usuario"required>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Fecha</label>
            <input type="TEXT" name="fecha" id="fecha" value= "<?php date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City"); echo date("Y/M/d"); ?>" readonly>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Hora de entrada:</label>
            <input type="time" name="hora_entrada" id="hora_entrada" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City"); echo date("H:i:s"); ?>" readonly>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="SUBMIT" value="Enviar" height="50">
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar" height="50">
        </li>
        </FORM>
</BODY>
```

Este es el PHP:

```
<?php
    include "conregistro.php";
    conecta();
    $Usuario=$_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $Fecha=$_REQUEST['fecha'];
    $Hora_entrada=$_REQUEST['hora_entrada'];
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,'utf8');
    $insertar=mysqli_query($conexion,
    "insert into horas (usuario,fecha,hora_entrada,hora_salida)
    values ('".$Usuario."','".$Fecha."','".$Hora_entrada."','".$Hora_entrada."');");        
    if(!$insertar)
        "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='Javascript' TYPE='text/Javascript'>
            alert('Error al intentar insertar datos')
            Javascript:history.back(1)
            </SCRIPT>";
    else
        echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='Javascript' TYPE='text/Javascript'>
            alert('Los datos se enviaron correctamente')
            window.location='../index.html'
            </SCRIPT>";
?>
```

Y la tabla de la BDD

`+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | ID           | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | usuario      | varchar(30) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
 | Fecha        | varchar(15) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
 | hora_entrada | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | hora_salida  | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

Por cierto, si estoy consciente de que la fecha lo tengo como un varchar; lo hice así para evitar problemas a la hora de insertar los datos ya que no se registraban

Comment: ¿Como identificas que el usuario es el mismo?

Comment: Cada usuario tiene que registrarse con en la tabla de usuarios, así que cada uno tiene una clave de usuario única e irrepetible

Comment: Ok, había entendido mal la pregunta. Si lo que quieres es que un usuario solo pueda registrarse una vez al día esta bien usar `unique` en la consulta, pero debes asegurarte de que es solo para ese usuario, sino no te dejará registrar ninguno mas.

Comment: En ese caso, al usar un `unique` en el usuario, los días posteriores le seria imposible registrarse, ¿No?

Comment: Debe ser único el usuario para esa fecha. Es decir, debes tener en cuenta tanto el campo usuario como el campo fecha.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!!!! Ya logre hacer que funcionara, hice lo que me dijiste sobre usar el `unique` en los dos campos y ahora funciona de forma correcta